# SMB protocol for copying files between remote shares

Tags: windows, robocopy, smb

I need to copy a lot of data from remote share \s1 to share \s2. I'm using robocopy, which uses SMB protocol to copy files. My question -- does the protocol allow to copy data from S1 to S2 directly or all data has to go through the machine on which robocopy is running?

Comment: It's called [server-side copy offload](http://blog.elastocloud.org/2013/11/samba-server-side-copy-offload.html). As noted [on the wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Server-Side_Copy), Robocopy takes advantage of it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the machine that it's running on. It copies the data from *source* in memory (on the current machine - *current*) and from there to *target*. There's no other way (well there could be a client/server running on *source*/*target* and the client is able to be configured remotely to open a tunnel directly to the server and transfer the files - but that's not the case here).

You can check this out by trying to *robocopy* a large file from *source* to *target* and using *Task Manager* monitor the network traffic on:

- *current* - incoming + outgoing
- *source* - outgoing
- *target* - incoming

and see that any of the following match (as expected):

- *source* - outgoing = *target* - incoming

but also these ones (where *current* comes into play):

- *source* - outgoing = *current* - incoming
- *current* - outgoing = *target* - incoming

To do it directly *robocopy* (or any other file transfer tool) must run on either *source* or *target*.

Comment: As Raymond pointed out, SMB *does* support doing the copy on the server.  If you've got two servers using the same SAN you can even copy from one server to another without the data ever leaving the SAN!  However, on Windows I believe the server has to be running Windows Server (not a client version of Windows) and both client and server have to be sufficiently recent - Windows 8 or later, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

server side copy is known to work only to/from {sub}directories within the same share;if you are considering copying ./between./ shares and maybe across servers then it is another feature you need to rely upon to speed up your transfers; it is called ODX and as Harry Johnston stated you need relatively new clients to avail of such a feature ==>

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2014/06/26/is-offloaded-data-transfers-odx-working/

[./.]"The computer initiating the data transfer must be running Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8.1, or Windows 8."[./.]

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831628.aspx