# Moving and Copying Remote Files

Tags: c#, .net, smb

I need to backup a file located on a remote machine using C#.

For example: "\server1\docs\test.txt" needs to be copied or moved to "\server1\docs\backup\test.txt."

Question: When I use File.Copy, does that move the file from the server, to my machine, back to the server -- essentially round-tripping the file across the network?

I'd like to avoid round-tripping.

Details: Both machines are Windows OS's on the same Domain.

Note: I want you guys to know that I have searched all over for the answer to this question, however, I have found contradicting answers. I'd like to know definitively. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMB protocol for copying files between remote shares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944769/smb-protocol-for-copying-files-between-remote-shares)

Answer (score 1):

You should run this from the server in order to avoid round-tripping the data. Keep in mind that if the files you're trying to work on are located on the same hard drive, moving them will be faster than copying them.

Comment: My situation won't allow me to add any processes to the remote server. What happens if I were to just rename the remote file? Would that prevent a round-trip?

Comment: can't you use powershell or ps tools to login into remote computer and issue the copy from there?

Comment: I don't see how would that make any difference. You are using a client to copy the file, that means that the server must first send the bytes to the client, and, in your case, the client is only sending them back onto another folder. Unless you can run the copy on the same machine (even a .bat file would be good for this kind of work), you are stuck having roundtrips.

Comment: @user1845593 the users running my program will only have read and write access to that one share.

Comment: @Av4t4r If simply renaming a file requires a round trip of the whole file, that is crazy. I would hope to think that SMB is smarter than that.

Comment: @JoshuaR it doesn't, it's a one way trip. Renaming the files won't help in any way to move or copy them however.

Comment: There is another post claiming that renaming a file or changing the directory is actually the same process. Assuming he is right, I'm curious if moving the file will cause a round-trip. I guess the only way to know for sure is using a network monitor.

Comment: I'm not sure where someone got that information, that is wrong.

Comment: @Av4t4r Geesh, there seems to be a lot of misinformation on this. If renaming the file doesn't trigger a round-trip, perhaps it would be more efficient to simply rename the file from test.txt to test_backup.txt. Would that do the trick?

Comment: Renaming the file isn't optimal but it beats moving a ~1 GB file across the network twice.

Comment: Sure. But it is still the same file on the same path, which is not part of your original question. You question states clearly that you intend to move the contents of a folder to a different one. Renaming a file **does not** accomplish the same result. It might be good enough for your case tho, and that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the source code of C# (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,4a0905e7dc32d77d) it seems that File.Copy calls Win32Native.CopyFile function. To be honest I don't know exactly what it does, I mean I never saw the code, but I guess there's no magic and it reads the bytes from the remote computer and writes to the other remote computer.

**Edit**

One alternative is to login into the remote server via powershell (you can invoke ps scripts via C#) and execute the command to copy to the 2nd machine.

Comment: I was surprised myself, there isn't a whole lot of documentation on the actual process of copying, moving, and renaming files from a remote machine. I've found several solutions on stack overflow, but the answers vary.

Comment: What the native win32 file copy exactly does depends on a lot of factors. On the used version of windows (on both sides), on the type of network access (SMB/NFS/...) ... there is no way to give a simple answer.